# How I can copy a table columns with data from one database to another database?

Tags: database, sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

The story is that I want to copy a table column data in a database to another table of another database. Both database are on same sql server 2005. Is this possible to copy the data in this manner or used to any software for do this.
I am using only one column with different table names and only copy the column data.
please do the needful.

Note: this question may be duplicate but I did not get the solutions.
thanks

Comment: Are there already records in the destination database?  That changes the complexity and possible approaches.  It means not only to we have to dumpt hte column data, but we also need to make sure we are dumping the data so that the new cells are added to the correct records.

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply copy rows from a source database to a target database, something like this should work, assuming the databases are on the same server, which you said they were:

```
Insert Into TargetDatabase.SchemaName.TableName (TargetColumn)
Select SouorceColumn
From SourceDatabase.SchemaName.TableName
```

If you want to synchronize rows (e.g., update or delete rows based on some criteria) between two tables in two different databases, this is far more complex. I would suggest a tool like Red-Gate Data Compare, or maybe some freeware app that does this. If you are using SQL Server 2008, the [MERGE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/28/sql-server-2008-introduction-to-merge-statement-one-statement-for-insert-update-delete/) statement might work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to sync the data vs doing a simple insert I highly recommend using the tools from http://www.red-gate.com/.  Specifically sql data compare.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Destitination Test2.dbo.AA not existing
Select * 
Into Test2.dbo.AA
from Test.dbo.AA

-- Destitination Test2.dbo.AA  existing
INSERT 
Into Test2.dbo.AA
Select *
from Test.dbo.AA
```